# If $G / \Phi(G)$ contains nontrivial normal subgroup whose order is not divisible by $p$, then so does $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

For a finite group $G$ denote by $\Phi(G)$ its Frattini subgroup, i.e. the intersection of all maximal subgroups of $G$.

> Let $p$ be a prime number. If $G / \Phi(G)$ contains a nontrivial normal subgroup whose order is not divisible by p, then so does $G$.

**My attempt**:  As $\Phi(G)$ is nilpotent, it is a direct product of its (unique) Sylow subgroups, and the Sylow subgroups of $\Phi(G)$ are characteristic in $\Phi(G)$, hence normal in $G$. So if $q \ne p$ is a different prime which does divides the order of $\Phi(G)$, then choose the unique Sylow $q$-subgroup $Q$ of $\Phi(G)$, and by the above $Q \unlhd G$, which shows that we have found such a normal subgroup in $G$.

If $\Phi(G) = 1$, then the hypothesis gives the claim immediately. So now suppose $P := \Phi(G)$ is a nontrivial $p$-group. I guess the Schur-Zassenhaus-Theorem plays a role (as it is an exercise from a book, appearing after the chapter on the this theorem). We have $(|P|, |N/P|) = 1$, as $P$ is normal we have a complement $H$ of $P$ in $N$, i.e. $N = PH$ with $H\cap P = 1$.

Now we have to construct somehow a normal subgroup, as the complements are conjugate, maybe the subgroup 
$$
 \bigcap_{g\in G} H^g = \bigcap_{g \in P} H^g
$$
(the last equality as they are already conjugate in $P$, as said in my book) might work. I recognize this intersection as the kernel of the (transitive) action of $P$ on the complements by conjugation, so one way might be to show that this action is not faithful. But here I am stuck, I have no idea how to proceed? But maybe my approach is wrong and leads nowhere?

Comment: By the Frattini Argument, $G = \Phi(G)N_G(H)$ and hence $G = N_G(H)$ and $H$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: why $G=N_G(H)$? [Here, say $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $\Phi(G)$ such that $K/\Phi(G)$ is normal in $G/\Phi(G)$ and has order not divisible by $p$. Then by Schur-Zassenhaus, $K=\Phi(G)\rtimes H$. Is this correct?]

Comment: For any subgroup $A$, you have $G=\Phi(G)A \Rightarrow G=A$: this is a standard exercise about the Frattini subgroup (If $A$ is proper, then it is contained in some maximal subgroup $M$, hence $G=\Phi(G)A \subseteq M$, contradiction).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, now I got it! Let $q \in \pi(H)$ and choose $Q \in \mbox{Syl}_q(H)$. Then $Q \in \mbox{Syl}_q(N)$ as $|N : Q| = |N : H||H : Q|$ is not divisible by $q$. Applying Frattini's Argument gives $G = NN_G(Q) = NN_G(H) = \Phi(G)HN_G(H) = \Phi(G)N_G(H)$, hence $G = N_G(H)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: No, the above is wrong I see... we do not have $N_G(Q) \le N_G(H)$... okay but we need a Sylow subgroup to apply Frattini, so where do you take it from?

Comment: No you don't need a Sylow subgroup, the fact that all complements of $P$ in $N$ are conjugate means that you can apply the Frattini Argument directly to $H$.

Comment: Yes, there exists a more general version, saying that if a subgroup $U$ acts transitive on some set $\Omega$, then $G = UG_{\alpha}$ for $\alpha \in \Omega$, I was to stacked onto the version just talking about Sylow subgroups.